# When opening my static website on Azure Storage I get a download screen

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm hosting a ReactJS app on a Azure Storage using the static website feature. Using this script:

```
$container = "`$web"
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $env:prSourceBranchName -StorageAccountKey "e4Nt0********dbFlEG2LN9g2i5/yQ=="
Get-ChildItem -Path $env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build -File -Recurse | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Confirm:$false -Force -Container $container -Context $context
```

I'm uploading the files from my build to the Azure storage $web blob.

[image]

When I navigate to the URL of the static page I get a download screen:

[image]

When I remove all the files and upload a simpel index.html file I does load the index.html file:

```
https://gist.github.com/chrisvfritz/bc010e6ed25b802da7eb
```

### EDIT

In Edge I can open the page but Chrome and Firefox load the download screen. But Firefox does show some more information:

[image]

[image]

So it looks like the content-type is a bit weird.

Comment: What is the extension of the URL?  Anything other than .htm and .html will probably be treated as a file because there is no web server to run server-side scripts and no htaccess to map other extensions to .htm and .html.  If an .htm page *includes* a .js or .css that will work because then the browser fetches those as files for building the page.

Comment: Hm this is weird. So I download the `index.html` file from the Blob and uploaded it manually and now the page loads. So I think there's a difference between uploading the file manually and using `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`

Comment: I think so, I had issue using Azure Powershell cmdlet and file encoding. I finally used az cli upload batch command to upload my static website files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The root cause should be the content-type is incorrect.

As you have already mentioned, when manually upload a .html file, it's content type is "`text/html`". While use `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`, it changes  to "`application/octet-stream`".

The solution is that when use powershell cmdlet `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`, you should specify the parameter `-Properties`, like below: `-Properties @{"ContentType" = "text/html"}`.

Sample code like below(It works at my side):

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "xxx" -StorageAccountKey "xxxxx"

#note that the last "\" is necessary
$path = "D:\temp\1\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path  -File -Recurse | `
 %{ if($_.extension -eq ".html") {Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $_.FullName -Blob $_.FullName.Replace($path,'')  -Container "test-1" -Context $context -Properties @{"ContentType" = "text/html"}} `
 else {Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $_.FullName -Blob $_.FullName.Replace($path,'') -Container "test-1" -Context $context}}
```

The above code just change the content_type of the files whose extension is .html to "text/html". You can feel free to change the code to meet your need.